# Add hover effect when use position:relative

Tags: html, css

I have the next component from antd in my react application: `<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />`.
I added hover effect when hover over the rows:

```css
.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
}

.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:last-of-type {
  position: relative;
  right: 27px;
}

.ant-table-tbody>tr.ant-table-row:hover>td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How you can see also i used position: relative for the `td` tag to move them from the end of the table. 
 Issue: When i hover the row you can notice 2 vertical lines on the row. When i remove position relative, the hover works ok. 
 Question: How to fix this issue but to keep the distance like is now with possiton relative? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4151-forked-qsqk8?file=/index.css:0-281

Comment: remove `position:relative` and add `padding-left` and `padding-right` for space

Comment: @MinalChauhan, `Question: How to fix this issue but to keep the distance like is now with possiton relative?`

Comment: ok, Using `position:relative` add `padding-left` and `padding-right` instead of `left` and `right` get some space

Comment: @MinalChauhan, i can't because i need to keep the space of the row borders. Ussing padding i will move only the text not the borders

Comment: [position:relative doesn't do what you think it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning). It sets the element so that descendant elements are positioned relative to ti.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a transition effect. You can solve it by adding

```css
.ant-table-tbody > tr > td {
  transition: none
}
```

I forked your CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4151-forked-gduct?file=/index.css

Comment: if i change the hover color `.ant-table-tbody > tr.ant-table-row:hover > td {
  background-color: rgba(345, 151, 248, .15);
}` the issue still. Could you help?

Comment: The issue is caused by this two rules `.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:first-of-type {
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
}` and `.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:last-of-type {
    position: relative;
    right: 27px;
}` remove `right` and 'left' attributes and the issue will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can used `:before` attributes add space on first and last `td` and remove `left` and `right` css

```
.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:first-of-type:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  width: 25px;
  height: calc(100% + 1px );
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:last-of-type {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-row .ant-table-cell:last-of-type:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 25px;
  height: calc(100% + 1px );
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.ant-table-tbody > tr.ant-table-row:hover > td{
  background-color: rgba(345, 151, 248, .15);
}
```

Code update [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4151-forked-qsqk8?file=/index.css)